# CheckComboBox choices are empty

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

Hi I am learning javafx and I want to create a dropdown with multiple select. I think I need to use CheckComboBox. I implement it but did no show the elements. Here`s my code:

In fxml : `<CheckComboBox fx:id="keywordBox" layoutX="233.0" layoutY="240.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="131.0" />`

In controller:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    final ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
         strings.add("Item " + i);
     }
keywordBox = new CheckComboBox<String>(strings);

keywordBox.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
     public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {
         System.out.println(keywordBox.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems());
     }
     });
}
```

And the dropdown is empty. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new CheckComboBox instead of using the one from the fxml.

Remove this line:

```
keywordBox = new CheckComboBox<String>(strings);
```

and add the items to the model of the existing keywordBox.